# resolve css3 bug with text rotate

Tags: css, webkit, border

Link to see the issue:

http://www.dev.pingag.ch/allsystems/fileadmin/templates/diagramm.html#

I created this diagramm with html and css. Around each word (integrität, innovation, etc.) is a div and one div is around everything.

The Text of the words "kompetenz" and "kunden" was rotated with:

```
    **-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);**
```

for Mozilla, Chrom and Opera.

For the Internet explorer I used:

**writing-mode:tb-rl;**

to rotate the text.

The result in the internet explorer is perfect but in Mozilla, Chrom and Opera **a unwanted white border appears** on top and bottom.

Do you have any Idea how I could resolve this problem?

thank you in advance

Comment: can you display more html/ css code please ?

Comment: You are modyfing the source of your site WHILE WE'RE WATCHING... -1, this is exactly the reason to post the HTML instead of referencing external sites (additionally to the fact that if the external sites are down or, in future, closed, noone will be able to access the question nor the answers), as explained in FAQS. Please create a Fiddle (http://jsFiddle.net/) to reproduce the problem, or at least post HTML and CSS... then the -1 will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just change the width of your divs
98px -> 100px for the left and right
and + 3-4px for the top right and bot right